# Node webkit - unable to fork a child process ( Error: spawn EACCES )

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, node-webkit

I have a piece of nodejs code ( [link](https://gist.github.com/bhavyaw/20856e8fb50324174c25f973e5ae4377) )  that is blocking. So, I am trying to run it in child process.

I am using the following code to **fork a child process** :

```
    var path = require('path');
    var nodeWebkitPath = path.dirname(process.execPath);
    var childProcess = require('child_process');

    var macEventDetectorChildProcess = childProcess.fork("./node/worker/osxEventsDetector.js",{
        execPath : nodeWebkitPath
    });
```

**Everytime i try to run my app with this code i get an error :**

```
Time :[Mon Sep 19 2016 13:16:42 GMT+0530 (IST)]
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:302:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:367:9)
    at Object.exports.fork (child_process.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Maneesh/Documents/productiveOne/productivity-front-desktopapp/src/nodeBootstrap.js:17:53)
    at Module._compile (module.js:431:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:446:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:375:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:332:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:483:10)
```

**Reading through some other answers on SO it seemed to be some permission related error but even after changing the permission for my project folder I am getting this error.**

**Other Details :**

1. OS - Mac
2. Node Webkit Version - 0.14.3

Any help / Suggestion to solve this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in Adavance.

Answer (score -1):

This a system issue. Try to run your application as administrator.

On linux/mac, you can do it with sudo:

```
sudo node app.js
```

On windows, start command line as administrator and run the app normally.

Comment: I am running my node-webkit app on mac machine. Have already tried sudo nw . ( command for starting the app ). Will try it on windows though to see if it works there.